How to Validate Select box through Jquery Validator
I have to validate select box through jquery validator.
<label class="form-label" for="inputState">Status</label>
<select id="inputState" name="status" class="form-control validate[required]">
 <option selected>Choose...</option>
 <option value="1">Active</option>
 <option value="0">Deactive</option>
</select>

$("#category_validation_form").validate({
            rules: {
                status: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });

Any help regarding to this is appreciated
Thanks in advance

You  must make the first value ="" - if you add required to the select tag, then no need for the validator

tried already but it didn't work
